# Accidental answer reported as spam

Tags: support

I accidentally reported [an answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/31794/1512) as spam. Is there anyway I can undo this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your most recent flag?

If so then it's easy. I just dismiss the flag.

As long as there are no more flags the answer won't get deleted and the user won't get the -100 reputation hit.

Comment: Yeah, it’s the latest one. OK, excellent.